# Apache .htaccess: allow directory listing for some users only

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to define different Options for different users in an .htaccess file?

I have a password-protected directory to which several different users have access.

I would like some users to have `Options +Indexes` and others to have `Options -Indexes`, and only be able to download files for which they have the direct link.